# Cargar Spinner desde base de datos sqlite Android

Tags: android, spinner

Estimados,estoy cargando un `Spinner` con información obtenida desde una tabla de base de datos `SQLite` de android,No tengo problemas en cargar el `Spinner` ,pero si al momento de obtener el dato seleccionado y almacenarlo en otra tabla de la base de datos.Esta es la manera que utilizo para cargar el `Spinner`.Les agradecería su orientación ya que soy nuevo en Android. Muchas Gracias.

```
BaseDatos bd  = new BaseDatos(getApplicationContext());

        final Cursor c = bd.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT id AS _id,nombre FROM Valores",null);

        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,new String[]{"nombre"},new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        spValores.setAdapter(null);
        spValores.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ¿lo que quieres es, obtener el valor que se seleccionó en el spinner?

Comment: si.correcto eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Prueba: int valorSeleccionado = spValores.getSelectedItemPosition(); y lo envías a la BD (la columna debe ser INTEGER): values.put(TuTabla.TU_COLUMNA, valorSeleccionado);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas el siguiente método:

```
TuSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        String ValorSeleccionado=TuSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); //Obtiene el valor del Spinner
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
```

Este método te permite realizar una acción cada que se cambia el item seleccionado, como puedes notar, en el ejemplo guardo en un String el valor que tiene el Spinner. También, el mismo método contiene un Listener para cuando no se selecciona nada en el Spinner, por si te llegara a hacer falta.

**EDIT**
Otra manera en la que puede funcionar, es que, guardes los resultados de tu consulta en un Arraylist, al menos del dato que necesitas mostrar en el Spinner, de tal manera, podrías recuperarlo de la siguiente manera: (el código propuesto va dentro de `OnItemSelected`)

```
String Valor = (String) TuArrayList.get(position);
```

Comment: implementando el método propuesto esto es lo que obtengo valor: spinner :android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41e76d98

Comment: el método `getSelectedItem().toString();` debería de traer lo que se está mostrando en el Spinner, dejame que revise bien que está pasando, se me hace algo curioso.

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta con otra manera de obtener los datos. @CristianBossardt

Comment: no logro dar con la solución,es curioso no poder obtener el dato seleccionado,ya que el Spinner se carga sin problemas con los valores desde la base de datos.

Comment: Para no abrir otra respuesta, me gustaría acompañar aquí una corrección basándome en tu primera respuesta. Si no me equivoco estas llenando el Spinner usando un Cursor, y es ahí donde te surge el problema, podrías intentar el mismo código propuesto por @L.Ronquillo cambiando la linea `String ValorSeleccionado=TuSpinner.getSelectedItem()....` de la siguiente manera: `String ValorSeleccionado = ((Cursor) TuSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getString(1);`

Comment: Estimados,he llegado a resolver el problema implementando la sugerencia propuesta por Israel.                                                               tvNombres.setText(((Cursor) spValores.getSelectedItem()).getString(1));
Agradezco enormemente todas las sugerencias y opiniones para resolver este problemas.Saludos